# Programmatically change geolocation

Tags: node.js

I am trying to test the scraping of a website that offers a different response based on geolocation. I can use a VPN to get the different responses, but I need to programmatically be able to switch countries using my VPN. Something like:

```
SetVPNCountry(USA)
GetResponse(www.xyz.com)
SetVPNCountry(China)
GetResponse(www.xyz.com)
```

Does anyone know what VPN supports this and can be run off AWS? I do not want to use multiple instances of servers.

Comment: You ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.